# How do I read in characters until the end (or right before the end) of a file?

Tags: c++, ifstream

What I need to do:

Read a text file of type ifstream called `textFile` one character `ch` at a time until `ch` is equal to a single quotation mark `'`. If ch is never equal to a quotation mark, print out fail and break out of the loop.

```
//read a character from the file into ch;
textFile.get(ch);
            // while ch is not a single quote
            while (ch != '\'')
            {
                //read in another character
                textFile.get(c);

                if (textFile.peek(), textFile.eof())
                  {
                     cout << "FAIL";
                     break;
                  }
            }
```

The textFile.txt that I am reading from has NO single quotes, therefore the output should be FAIL.

However when I print it, it prints fail twice. Any help is appreciated

Comment: `if (textFile.peek(), textFile.eof())` Not sure what you expected this to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ifstream::get(char& c)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) will return the `ifstream` object that is used to read, and it can be used as condition to check if the reading was successful. Use it.

Your code should be like this:

```
char c, ch;
// while ch is not a single quote
do
{
    //read in another character
    // you can use ch directly here and remove the assignment ch = c; below if you want
    if(!textFile.get(c))
    {
       cout << "FAIL";
       break;
    }
    ch = c;
} while(ch != '\'');
```